# Pandas convert integer into date

Tags: date, pandas

So I have a DataFrame object called 'df' and im trying to covert the 'timestamp' into a actual readable date.

```
     timestamp
0   1465893683657       
1   1457783741932   
2   1459730006393   
3   1459744745346   
4   1459744756375
```

Ive tried

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='s')
```

but this gives

```
     timestamp
0   1970-01-01 00:24:25.893683657   
1   1970-01-01 00:24:17.783741932   
2   1970-01-01 00:24:19.730006393   
3   1970-01-01 00:24:19.744745346   
4   1970-01-01 00:24:19.744756375
```

which is clearly wrong since I know the date should be either this year or last year.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with unit `ms`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms'))
0   2016-06-14 08:41:23.657
1   2016-03-12 11:55:41.932
2   2016-04-04 00:33:26.393
3   2016-04-04 04:39:05.346
4   2016-04-04 04:39:16.375
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: neither answers work for me. I get the same results as before. Some more info: type(df['timestamp']) --> gives --> pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: Maybe there are some bad data - use `(pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms', errors='coerce'))` for convert them to `NaN`. also you can check this rows by `print df[pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms', errors='coerce').isnull()]`

Comment: also if I do df.timestamp = df.timestamp.to_datetime() I get the error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: df[pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms', errors='coerce').isnull()] returns an empty dataframe

Comment: print (pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='ms', errors='coerce')) also gives the wrong answers, like before

Comment: sorry ;-) my bad, i was doing something wrong, your answer works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the significant digits or better use @jezrael's unit ('ms').

```
In [133]: pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp // 10**3, unit='s')
Out[133]:
0   2016-06-14 08:41:23
1   2016-03-12 11:55:41
2   2016-04-04 00:33:26
3   2016-04-04 04:39:05
4   2016-04-04 04:39:16
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```